# Timing-out a series of async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to execute a series of asynchronous functions, one after another.

And I'd like to stop the waterfall after, say, 10 seconds, even if the last few functions have not finished.

This is the only solution I could think of:

```
async function () {
  let timeout = false

  setTimeout(() => {
    timeout = true
  }, 10 * 1000)

  let a = await firstPromise()
  if (timeout) return
  let b = await secondPromise(a)
  if (timeout) return
  let c = await thirdPromise(b)
  if (timeout) return
  let d = await fourthPromise(c)
  // and so forth
}
```

Is this the most elegant way of tackling the problem?

Comment: `most elegant` - that would be a matter of opinion :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is pretty great. It would be possible to generalize it further, but this only works if your process is indeed very generic and I would probably not use this unless you have a few different places where you can re-use this exact process.

```
async foo (...funcs) {
  let timeout = false

  setTimeout(() => {
    timeout = true
  }, 10 * 1000)

  let lastResult;

  for(func of funcs) {
    lastResult = await func(lastResult);
    if (timeout) return;
  }

}

foo(
  firstPromise,
  secondPromise,
  thirdPromise,
  fourthPromise
);
```

Comment: This makes sense. It's probably part of a library somewhere.